# Python: Difference between filter(function, sequence) and map(function, sequence)

Tags: python, functional-programming, map-function, filterfunction

I'm reading through the Python documentation to really get in depth with the Python language and came across the filter and map functions. I have used filter before, but never map, although I have seen both in various Python questions here on SO.

After reading about them in the Python tutorial, I'm confused on the difference between the two. For example, from [5.1.3. Functional Programming Tools](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
>>> def f(x): return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0
...
>>> filter(f, range(2, 25))
[5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23]
```

and

```
>>> def cube(x): return x*x*x
...
>>> map(cube, range(1, 11))
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000]
```

These looked almost exactly the same in function to me, so I went into terminal to run Python interactively and tested out my own case. I used `map` for both the first and second instances above, and for the first one ( `return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0` ) it returned a list of booleans rather than numbers.

Why does `map` sometimes return a boolean and other times the actual return value?

Can someone explain to me exactly the difference between `map` and `filter`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
list(map(cube, range(1, 11)))
```

is equivalent to

```
[cube(1), cube(2), ..., cube(10)]
```

While the list returned by

```
list(filter(f, range(2, 25)))
```

is equivalent to `result` after running

```
result = []
for i in range(2, 25):
    if f(i):
        result.append(i)
```

Notice that when using `map`, the items in the result are values returned by the function `cube`.

In contrast, the values returned by `f` in `filter(f, ...)` are not the items in `result`. `f(i)` is only used to determine **if** the value `i` should be kept in `result`.

---

In Python2, `map` and `filter` return lists. In Python3, `map` and `filter` return iterators. Above, `list(map(...))` and `list(filter(...))` is used to ensure the result is a list.

Comment: list(map(cube, range(1, 11))) is equivalent to [cube(1), cube(2), ..., cube(10)].

Answer (score 26):

`filter()`, as its name suggests, filters the original iterable and retents the items that returns `True` for the function provided to `filter()`.

`map()` on the other hand, apply the supplied function to each element of the iterable and return a list of results for each element.

Follows the example that you gave, let's compare them:

```
>>> def f(x): return x % 2 != 0 and x % 3 != 0
>>> range(11)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> map(f, range(11))  # the ones that returns TRUE are 1, 5 and 7
[False, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False]
>>> filter(f, range(11))  # So, filter returns 1, 5 and 7
[1, 5, 7]
```

Comment: that makes sense now, i see how the filter term suggests what the function does versus map.

Comment: Actually the name `map()` makes sense as well, in some field when map is used as a verb it means to find 1 to 1 corresponding relationship. Such as in math: 'map x to y' or in genetics: 'map diabetes to a gene'. One thing nice about `Python` is just like this: the names often make sense.

Comment: that's a good point. It's funny how similar certain aspects of programming are to everyday examples. Like i'm in algebra 2 and we're learning about functions f(x) and half the class is stumped but the idea is 100% similar to functions in programming.

Answer (score 4):

`map` and `filter` function in python is pretty different because they perform very differently. Let's have a quick example to differentiate them.

**map function**

Let's define a function which will take a string argument and check whether it presents in vowel letter sequences.

```
def lit(word):
    return word in 'aeiou'
```

Now let's create a map function for this and pass some random string.

```
for item in map(lit,['a','b','e']):
    print(item)
```

And yes it's equivalent to following

```
lit('a') , lit('b') , lit('e')
```

simply it will print

```
True
False
True
```

**filter function**

Now let's create a `filter` function for this and pass some random string.

```
for item in filter(lit,['a','b','e']):
    print(item)
```

`filter` as the name implies, filters the original iterable and retents the items that return True for the function provided to the filter function.

Simply it will print

```
a
e
```

Fork it [here](https://gist.github.com/iphton/51347f00c575c4a319c5522d4ef5bb11) for future reference, if you find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Filter**--Returns the true value's position

---

```
var_list = [10,20,0,1]

var_b = list(filter(lambda var_a : var_a*2,var_list))

print("Values are",var_b)
```

*Output*

---

Values are [10, 20, 1]

**Map**--Returns the actual result

---

```
var_list = [10,20,0,1]

var_b = list(map(lambda var_a : var_a*2,var_list))

print("Values are",var_b)
```

*Output*

---

Values are [20, 40, 0, 2]

**Reduce**--Take the first 2 items in the list,then calls function,
In next function call,the result of previous call will be 1st argument and 3rd item in list will be 2nd argument

---

```
from functools import *

var_list = [10,20,0,1]

var_b = list(map(lambda var_a : var_a*2,var_list))

print("Values of var_b ",var_b)

var_c = reduce(lambda a,b:a*2,var_b)

print("Values of var_c",var_c)
```

*Output*

---

Values of var_b  [20, 40, 0, 2]

Values of var_c 160

Answer (score 0):

filter(function, iterable) function (pointer, like in C) return boolean type

map(function, iterable) function (pointer, like in C) return e.g. int

```
def filterFunc(x):
    if x & 1 == 0:
        return False
    return True


def squareFunc(x):
    return x ** 2


def main():
    nums = [5, 2, 9, 4, 34, 23, 66]
    odds = list(filter(filterFunc, nums))   # filter(function, iterable)
    print(odds)

    square = list(map(squareFunc, nums))    # map(function, iterable)
    print(square)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```